\input with multicols pagebreaks
I have multiple .tex files that I insert into a main document.tex file. This is done for separating the different parts of my paper. The .tex files that are called with \input in document.tex contain a two column text defined with
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\end{multicols*}

My problem is, whenever I call a new \input{chapter1.tex} in the main file document.tex it page breaks. What I want to happen is regardless of how much a chapter1.tex file takes up from a page, I want the next chapter2.tex file to start where the first file ended, not on a new page. How do I do this?

That is the normal behavior of the \chapter command. If you use the memoir class it has facilities to do what you are asking. since you refer to a paper you write, maybe use the article class and section rather than chapter.

@yannisl I'm not using a \chapter command, the name of the file as chapter.tex is only for example. Also, if the usage of the article class you're refering to is \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} then I'm already using it.

I think is best if you can post a minimal example so we can see exactly what you see, as well the class and packages you using.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

do not use multicols* but multicols. If you don't balance the columns, a pagebreak is forced.

Unless you want   one  and  two columns in the same pages,  probably is better do not use multicols  in every child document, that disable float mechanisms,   but just the twocolumn option in \documentclass of the main file.  You can also use  \onecolumn and \twocolumn to switch from 1 to 2 columns or vice versa, but  this always start a new page  (i.e., you cannot have  1 and  2 columns in the same page in this way). If this is a issue, while  having disabled floats is not, then multicol is the logical option.
